# Using Geo Data Store Plugin Code

Tags: oop

I'm trying to simply use the Geo Data Store Plugin Code functions from within my theme files and have never done this. I've tested the $sc_gds to see if isset, yet not getting anything when looping the array (eventually to loop through them as map markers)

```
$type = "post_type";
$sc_gds = new sc_GeoDataStore();
$ids = (array) $sc_gds->getPostIDsOfInRange( $type, $radius, $lat, $lng );
foreach ($ids as $id) {
print $id;
}
```

Can someone explain how to use plugin file's public static functions and any information for using getPostIDsOfInRange would be appreciated greatly.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is exactly. if `echo $ids` outputs `Array`, then the result is an array, which can't be echoed, that's just basic php. use `print_r` to see the contents of the array, or `foreach` to loop over the results.

Comment: Yes, thank you. However I still can't get values from it?

Comment: before your `foreach` add `print_r($ids)`. PS, Why are you casting the results as an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted the Geo Data Store plugin and reinstalled, in which my code worked upon refresh. I was able to use the functions from the plugin and so on. I casted as an array so as to use the output in my wp_query arguments

```
$sc_gds = new sc_GeoDataStore();
$ids = (array) $sc_gds->getPostIDsOfInRange( $type, $radius, $lat, $lng );
$args = array('post__in' => $ids, 'post_type' => 'custom_post_type');
```